# Jms Gateway Unable to refresh MQ connection

Tags: spring-integration

I have an inbound gateway which is listening to MQ for messages. Whenever the MQ server is bought down. I loose the connection and in the logs I see that my inbound gateway tries to refresh the connection every 5 seconds. But once the MQ server is up I still see the same error in the log. Can you please let me know if I'm missing any info from the config or is there anything to be done on the MQ server.

Spring Config

```
<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory1" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"> 
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory1"/> 
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mqConnectionFactory1" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter"> 
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory"> 
        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"> 
            <property name="hostName" value="${mq.hostname.1}"/> 
            <property name="port" value="${mq.port}"/> 
            <property name="queueManager" value="${mq.queuemanager.1}"/> 
            <property name="transportType" value="${mq.transporttype}"/>
            <property name="channel" value="${mq.channel}"/>
        </bean> 
    </property> 
    <property name="username" value="${mq.username}"/>
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
        id="mqEnterpriseRequestAdapter1" 
        connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory1" 
        destination="xyzQueue"
        concurrent-consumers="2"
        max-concurrent-consumers="5"
        cache-level="5" 
        idle-consumer-limit="5"
        max-messages-per-task="2"
        channel="xyzReceive"/>
```

Error Log:

```
[2015-09-19 01:52:56,267]  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#4-494492] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:842) - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///queuename' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2019
[2015-09-19 01:52:51,292]  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#4-494037] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:842) - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///queuename' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2019
[2015-09-19 01:52:51,263]  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#4-494488] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:842) - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///queuename' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2019
[2015-09-19 01:52:46,291]  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#4-494033] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:842) - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///queuename' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2019
[2015-09-19 01:52:46,262]  WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#4-494485] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:842) - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///queuename' - trying to recover. Cause: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to your question by googling `MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2019`

The answer is [on IBM's support site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21229508).

> Reason code 2019 usually occurs after a connection broken error (reason code 2009) occurs. You would see a JMSException with reason code 2009 preceding reason code 2019 in the SystemOut.log.
>
> Reason code 2009 indicates that the connection to the MQ queue manager is no longer valid, usually due to a network or firewall issue.
>
> Reason code 2019 errors will occur when invalid connections remain in the connection pool after the reason code 2009 error occurs. The next time that the application tries to use one of these connections, the reason code 2019 occurs.

Comment: Thanks Gary I saw that link about setting the purge policy. Should I be setting it on the MQConnectionFactory or is there something in the CachingConnectionFactory. Because If I use UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter other than the CachingConnectionFactory I'm able to reconnect.

Comment: Just like the `UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter `, the `CachingConnectionFactory` knows nothing about IBM proprietary settings; you always set such things on the underlying vendor factory that's wrapped in a CCF or UCCF.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after following the below post and the config changes after the modification
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/89532-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-cachingconnectionfactory-tomcat-and-websphere-mq

```
<bean id="mqContainer1" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory1" />
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="cachingConnectionFactory1" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${mq.requestqueue}" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="x"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="x"/>
    <property name="maxMessagesPerTask" value="x"/>
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="x"/>
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
        id="mqEnterpriseRequestAdapter1" 
        container="cbatsMqContainer1"
        channel="mqMessageReceive"/>
```